# highcharts check if a piechart section is selected

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am unable to find anything in Highcharts API that lets loop through sections of a pie chart and detect which sections are selected. Something like "isSelected()" is missing.

Has anyone tried this before.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look harder, see: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.getSelectedPoints

> getSelectedPoints ()  Since 1.2.0
>
> Returns an array of all currently selected points in the chart. 
>      Points can be selected either programmatically by the point.select() method or by clicking.

And http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.selected:

> selected Since 1.2.0
>
> Whether the point is selected or not.